# Balance RabbitMQ master queues across nodes

Tags: rabbitmq, load-balancing

I have a cluster of 3 RabbitMQ nodes and I want to keep master queues balanced across all nodes, even after node reboots. Still, master queues don't rebalance when a new node joins the cluster or when one of the nodes disconnects and reconnects.

Example: I create 100 queues on nodes A, B and C.
If node C shutdowns, master queues from C are almost equally rebalanced between node A and B. So at this point, nodes A and B have both approximately 50 master queues.
Now, if I reconnect node C, it'll remain with 0 master queues until new queues are created. This is problematic because I want all my nodes to produce the same amount of work.

My exchanges are durables, my queues are durables and mirrored and my messages are persistent. I want to avoid loosing messages.

I know there is a way to [change the master node manually using a policy trick](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/rabbitmq-users/bJNcrDVhWiU/6oMO0DjNQ4oJ). But this is not satisfying since it breaks HA (by inducing a resynchronisations of all mirrors).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this command:

```
rabbitmq-queues rebalance type --vhost-pattern pattern --queue-pattern pattern
```

for example

```
rabbitmq-queues rebalance "all" --vhost-pattern "a-vhost" --queue-pattern ".*"
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use [Federated Queues](https://www.rabbitmq.com/federated-queues.html).

> A federated queue links to other queues (called upstream queues). It will retrieve messages from upstream queues in order to satisfy demand for messages from local consumers.

You can create a completely new cluster which is both upstream and downstream from the original cluster. You also need to ensure that both your publishers and consumers reconnects periodically (to avoid one cluster to monopolize all connections, defeating load-balancing).

As you pointed out, there's also Simon MacMullen's trick from [`rabbitmq-users`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/rabbitmq-users/bJNcrDVhWiU/6oMO0DjNQ4oJ) group.

```
# rabbitmqctl set_policy --apply-to queues --priority 100 my-queue '^my-queue$' '{"ha-mode":"nodes", "ha-params":["rabbit@master-node"]}'
# rabbitmqctl clear_policy my-queue
```

But it has the underdesirable side-effect to make mirrors loose synchronisation for a while. This might be acceptable or not, depending on your requirements, so I think it's worth saying it's possible.

More advanced technique might come up in 4.x, but it is not sure at all.

Comment: [`queue-master-locator` strategy](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html#master-migration-data-locality) ; [Michael Klishin's hint for improvements in 4.x](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/issues/332#issuecomment-278592296) (sorry, had to post this as a separate comment since I lack reputation to post more than 2 links per answer)

Comment: Simon MacMullen's trick is not 100%HA because while you are doing it, there is a moment your queue is not mirrored anymore, wich mean at this exact moment you can completely loose your queue. Also, synchronizing freeze the queue while doing it (if I understood the function correctly), wich is pretty bad if this happen at the wrong moment.

And about Feredation... Considering you constantly move messages from one node-queue couple to another node-queue couple, this doesn't really reduce the charge on one node, and instead use even more CPU since the 2nd node now work more !

Comment: You are right and understood correctly. I totally understand you knew the trick but cannot use it (I wouldn't recommend it in most cases). About federated queues, you are also kind of right. As stated in the docs, it works better if you have some sort of locality. Yet, since messages might come up on one side or the other, load is balanced and slightly lowered per node. To leverage the locality, you may publish messages in a round-robin style, and consume them from both clusters. This way, locality is insured, and load is almost perfectly balanced. You keep federation only for edge-cases.

Comment: However, I really doubt that queues syncs produce the freeze you describe. Do you have any reference for this? I think you just have to ensure that the slave queue is fully synchronized with the master queue when you switch. And as soon as you switch, the new slave (former master) will have to resychronize (which basically means that every message that was in the queue when switching will have to be consumed). If you loose the new master before having consumed all messages, unsychronized messages will be lost. This is a shorthand to adding new nodes to the cluster and destroying the old ones.

Comment: https://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html

"Since the queue becomes unresponsive while explicit synchronisation is occurring, it is preferable to allow active queues from which messages are being drained to synchronise naturally, and only explicitly synchronise inactive queues."

My comprehension of the following doc is that, while synchronizing, both master and host are not available.

Comment: Unlike `sync_queue`, applying a policy to a queue is not an "explicit synchronisation request". Explicit synchronisation will indeed force both queues to be in sync (which is only possible by locking the master and thus breaking availability). However, applying the policy will only make the queue loose synchronisation, not force them to be in sync again. Consequently, as stated in doc, queues will naturally sync themselves over time without being unavailable. The only risk is to loose a master node before the two queues are completely in sync. In this case, unsynced messages are lost.

Comment: Yeah exactly, that's what I understood from the doc and all topics I read. Thanks for your feedback tho. The problem is that I would like to find a 100% HA solution if possible. But this could indeed do the trick, i just don't like to "believe" and hope that things won't go from bad to worse in a professionnal environnement.

Comment: Yup. To sum it up, if no trade off on HA or performance are possible, multi-cluster + federated queues + random publishers + multiple-consumers would be the solution I'd choose.